# c++/cli instantiating IDbDataParameter

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C# it is possible to instantiate an array of the IDbDataParameter interface:

```
IDbDataParameter [] DbParams = new IDbDataParameter[3];
```

Is there any way it can be done in C++/cli?
The code compiles when I declare an array of IDbDataParameter:

```
array<IDbDataParameter^>^ dbParams = gcnew array<IDbDataParameter^>(3);
```

But I am not able to find a way to instantiate IDbDataParameter using gcnew:

```
dbParams[0] = gcnew IDbDataParameter[1];
```

> error C2728: 'System::Data::IDbDataParameter' : a native array cannot
>   contain this managed type Did you mean
>   'array'?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are ;-) IDbDataParameter is an interface, you cannot create instances of interface (neither in C++ nor in C#). It should be something like `dbParams[0] = gcnew SqlDbDataParameter()`.

Comment: Thanks, I know, however in C# it is possible to instantiate an array of IDbDataParameter instances. **IDbDataParameter [] DbParams = new IDbDataParameter[3];** is valid.
By the way what is **SqlDbDataParameter** ?

Comment: Thanks very much Soner. It looks like 

dbParams[0] = gcnew SqlParameter();

works fine.

Comment: @PMF
Well, when you are right you are right Soner.
IDbDataParameter [] DbParams = new IDbDataParameter[3];
Instantiates an **array** of IDbDataParameter(s) but does not instantiate any IDbDataParameter.
I must have lost my 3/4 of the brain today.